# Finding Edges and Vertices Within Heightmap Array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, terrain

Lets say I have generated a heightmap array, which for simplicity's sake will only have three height values within it: `0`,`1`, and `2`. For example, it may look like this:

```
000000111111110000000000000000000000000000000000
001111111111111111000000000001111111111111000000
000011111111111111100000000000000011122111110000
000000000111111100000000000000000111221110000000
000000000000000000000000000001111122222111111100
000000000000000000000000111111111111111111000000
000000000000000000000111111111100000000000001111
000000000001111111111110000000000000000001111111
000000001111222222211100000000000000000000001110
000000000011112221100000000000000011111000000000
000000000000111111100000000000001111111110000000
000000001111111110000000000000000011111000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

What I'm trying to do is find the 'vertices' in this heightmap, and to output them in a logical order (so I can draw a line going to each consecutive point that will eventually trace the outline of the shape). For example, for the first 'group' of `1`s in the top right corner:

```
000000111111110000000           .1------2       
001111111111111111000        8-'         `--3   
000011111111111111100  -->    `7---.        .4  
000000000111111100000               6-----5'    
000000000000000000000
```

The numbers in the second diagram are the coordinates I need to find (in the correct order), and the dots and dashes are the lines I would trace from each point to get the outline of the shape.

Is there any sort of algorithm I can use to find these vertices? If not, what is the most efficient method of finding them?

What I am currently doing is using recursion to find each of the 'islands' or 'groups' of numbers, and then taking all the outer points of this shape as the vertices. However, my method is quite slow and the vertices are not in the correct order.

Thank you for your help and I hope this all makes sense.

**Edit:**
I realize from the comments that using vertices would make me lose some areas of the shape. I think that instead of vertices then what I need to find is **all** the points on the edge of the shape, but in the correct order. So my example should be:

```
000000111111110000000             12345678       
001111111111111111000         17          9,10   
000011111111111111100  -->     16,15         11  
000000000111111100000               14,13,12     
000000000000000000000
```

Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Assuming the heightmap is in an array `A` and the top left is cell `A[0][0]`, why is `A[1][6]` (row 1, column 6) not a vertex? How do you decide where to put diagonal lines? If you were to calculate the convex hull, then those would be the vertices, but the sides of the hull would not preserve those dents.

Comment: The lines are only there so its easier to see the shape they trace. I was trying to make it look like a diagonal line from `8` to `1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Answer to the edited question:) A certain form of graph traversal should do for this, I will only give a very high-level description of it. Start at the highest level of the height map, and for any island, start at some interior point. Go north until you reach the edge of the island or the edge of the map. In a clockwise (or counter-clockwise, whichever it is you need) fashion, explore only those cells that can belong to the edge of the island.

For lower levels, start from cells neighboring the higher-level islands and do the same.

---

(Answer to question before clarifying edit:)
Sounds to me like you want the [convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) of every "island". Find contiguous groups (your "islands") with graph traversal (I like [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) best, but tastes differ; consider two cell to belong to the same island whenever they contain the same value and are adjacent), then apply some [convex hull algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms).

Comment: What if one the islands was shaped like the letter c or like a donut? Looking at images of the convex hull method it appears as though it would not get the correct shape as in [this](http://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/~algorith/files/convex-hull-R.gif) image

Comment: The image is exactly the shape you would get. Is that not the one you want? You will have to define the shapes more clearly then.

Comment: For a shape that is curved or has dents inside, such as the letter c or the letter s, wouldn't using the convex hull method would just give me two ovals?

Comment: You would get one oval for either, yes. I take it you would want to keep some concave bits, and some you wouldn't? If that's the case, then you will have to define which to keep and which to gloss over in order for others to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try alpha shapes. Alpha shapes is defined as a delaunay triangulation without edges exceeding alpha.